# Why ASP MVC application is considered as a Project not a Website?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been developing ASP websites and MVC applications for over an year, but never thought why the MVC Application is placed under projects category in Visual Studio? why not under Websites?

Comment: What can you do... if you can't do anything :D

Comment: Isn't it, you are asking difference between website and web application

Comment: I am not asking the difference between a website and web application... I am asking why it is categorized as a Project not as a Website

Comment: Have a look at this : http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/10/aspnet-difference-between-website-and.html

Comment: @TusharGupta - Projects have Project files, Websites do not.  ie. .csproj or .vbproj.  Websites have no "project" associated with them, they're just a collection of files in a website folder, which is one of the problems with them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You really shouldn't be developing ASP Websites.  You should be developing ASP Web Applications.  In my not so humble opinion, Website projects should die a horrible death.

There are a lot of differences between the two, and Websites have a lot of problems associated with them.  For instance, they don't use namespaces by default.. so it's really easy to cause naming collisions unintentionally.

There is a big list of the differences here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590(v=vs.110).aspx

Website projects cause all kinds of problems with deployment, debugging, structuring enterprise applications... MVC doesn't use them because they're evil, and because it's really not possible to use them and achieve the goals that MVC tries to achieve, which is separation of concerns, testability, modularity, etc...

Website projects don't have project files, ie. a .csproj file.  Thus, there is no way to define which specific files are included or not in the project, what settings to use, or any of a number of other things provided by project files.  Websites use conventions, like adding suffixes to files to exclude them from compilation, which is error prone and difficult to manage.

It's this lack of project file that differentiates them between "Websites" and "Projects".